# Publishing Pre-Compiled ASP.net-MVC VS2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, deployment

I found several solutions which use Post-Build event.

Is there a way to **publish** ASP.NET MVC web site **with compiled views** (to prevent first user view delay) but **do not compile** them **in development environment** (to compile site faster)?

Thank you!

P.S. Ideally it would be to configure One Click Publish feature in Visual Studio 2010

**Edit**

As I understood `<AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(WebProjectOutputDir)" />` does the same thing as

```
 <MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
 <EnableUpdateable>false</EnableUpdateable>
```

but for early versions

My .csproj looks like

```
...
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
    <EnableUpdateable>false</EnableUpdateable>
...
```

and views precompile fine but I can't get a single library for deployment like with Asp .net applications. That's why first load page delay still exist...

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the post-build event to compile views only when you compile in Release mode so that it does not slow you down during development (when you presumably compile in Debug mode.)

For example, the following node in a .csproj will only compile views when the project is compiled in Release mode.

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'">
    <AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(WebProjectOutputDir)" />
  </Target>
```

Comment: Hector thank you! I've found that it compiles views on build but the first time page loading still takes more time than following loadings. Is it possible to remove that delay?

Comment: I don't know of any built-in feature for that. Keep in mind that the delay on the first load might also be due to other factors like the first data access.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can set MvcBuildViews to true, but only do it for certain configurations:

```
<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>

<Target Name="MvcBuildViews" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true' And '$(Configuration)'!='Debug'">
    <AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(WebProjectOutputDir)" />
</Target>
```

Notice i've added `And '$(Configuration)'!='Debug'"` to the condition.