# Improve first request time after DLL change in IIS .NET MVC site

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, dll

As you may know, updating an IIS (v8) site's `bin` folder causes a delay in serving the next request. On a smallish app of mine hosted on one server this lasts about 20 seconds.

On a live site with requests coming in every second or so, auto-warmup doesn't make a difference.

What is the bottleneck that causes this delay and what strategies are there to minimise it? My thoughts so far:

1. Increase CPU power of the server or the speed of RAM / SSD etc. But which?
2. Split the project into a number of smaller DLLs so the amount to reload is smaller - would this work?
3. Have two physical versions on the server in different folders. Have the application point to the old version, update the DLL in the other, do a first request, then switch the application to point to the updated folder. But maybe switching physical locations will also cause this delay?

Thoughts appreciated.

Comment: i gess you should try [precompile your project before publishing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038053/publishing-pre-compiled-asp-net-mvc-vs2010).

Comment: Hmm so you think the delay is caused by recompiling views? I have found that if I update the view files, there is no (or minimal) delay. It's only when I update the DLL

Comment: but you also can precompile dll according to your platform, i gess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you publish the application (or changing a `bin` item) it will create a new instance of the w3wp.exe process. This is the web process where the application memory is stored (keeping it simple). If you publish you are creating a new instance and the old is getting destroyed.

All sessions will be lost.

For example, every time you publish the website, it will make a change to web.config. This will cause the application to unload and IIS to recycle.

Causes:

- Web.config Changes
- bin folder content change
- Manual IIS applicaiton
  pool recycle

Your points 1 & 2 will make no difference to your problem what-so ever. Your 3rd point will again cause an App pool recycle, this will cause a delay.

A solution to this would be to possibly use a load balanced server environment. You can then update one server while pointing to load to the other, perform a few requests on the updated version so it `JIT`'s then swap the users to that server and do the same on the second.

Comment: Thank you. Very useful. I think what you're referring to in the last para is what I mean by point 3: to simulate a load balancer by having two versions of the site running side by side (in different app pools?) and then somehow switch from one to the other once one has been updated. But how do you do this? By editing the bindings? Seems risky...

I use state session server so I'm not worried about losing sessions.

Comment: It depends on your infrastructure. I cannot answer that, if you have a physical loadbalancer it would be different to having a virtual. What you want is a 'staging' environment where you make your changes and then switch over. Then the 'old' environment becomes your staging. You could do it by editing the bindings.